# libspotify: does relogin work for normal premium account?

Tags: spotify

As per the API document, **sp_session_relogin** can be used to log in the remembered user if last user that logged in with remember_me set. If my program login once with "remember_me" set to 1 in **sp_session_login**, will the user credential be stored somewhere? Can I use **sp_session_relogin** to login back after logout the program? or under what kind of situation can **sp_session_relogin" be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct about how `relogin` works. However, the credentials will only be successfully stored for use next time if you correctly log out and wait for the logout completed callback before terminating your application.

Comment: I believe I logged out the program correctly - wait for the logout callback and then release the session. But relogin never works if I tried to login again without username/password. I don't know if it's because of the session is different between the first time login and relogin. Also tried without release the session after log-out, but still can't relogin as SP_ERROR_NO_CREDENTIALS is set.

Comment: sp_session_relogin doesn't take a username/password. Also, make sure you're giving valid cache and settings values when you init the session each time, and are using the same values and not clearing the cache.

Comment: Thank you very much! My code may have a bug somewhere so it doesn't save the credential properly. Anyway I tried the example code "spshell" which works with the relogin. From what I've tried, relogin doesn't trigger **logged_in** callback; it works for browsing but doesn't work for the API **sp_session_playlistcontainer** which always returns NULL. Also I'm curious how faster relogin is compared with login? I can't tell the difference from user experience.

Comment: Relogin does trigger the login callback — your problem is that login hasn't finished yet, which is why you don't get a playlist container. There are no performance differences between the two given identical network conditions.